# List with multiple columns of different length in Latex

Tags: latex

I want to have a structure in Latex where I have multiple lists next to each other that have different length and are generally not associated to each other:

```
list 1       list 2       list 3
- item a     - item w     - item k
- item b     - item x     - item l
- item c     - item y
             - item z
```

Ideally, I should be able to manipulate each of these lists individually very easily.

Comment: What should happen around the page boundary? The assumption is that these lists will remain together and not necessarily break partially across the page boundary.

Comment: yes, the lists should stay together, meaning if one list is longer and goes across a page boundary, all lists should move to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create each list as a column within a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\addvspace{\medskipamount}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} X X X @{} }
  List 1

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item a
    \item item b
    \item item c
  \end{itemize} &
  List 2

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item w
    \item item x
    \item item y
    \item item z
  \end{itemize} &
  List 3

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item k
    \item item l
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Or, set each list inside a `[t]`op-aligned `minipage` that will fit across the line width (similar to the above technique):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\addvspace{\medskipamount}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3333\linewidth}
  List 1

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item a
    \item item b
    \item item c
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3333\linewidth}
  List 2

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item w
    \item item x
    \item item y
    \item item z
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3333\linewidth}
  List 3

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item k
    \item item l
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\addvspace{\medskipamount}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```